# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] - tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, catalina

I am trying to get my tomcat 8.5 to start on my eclipse.
Everytime I get this error.

I already tried the below fixes but nothing seems to work:

- Added log4j.jar to my classpath
- cleaned Tomcat Directory
- My JDK is 1.8
- My JRE is 1.8

Any idea what else to try?

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1144)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1878)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Logger;     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my issue.
My lib folder was outside the WebContent folder...
I copied it inside `WebContent/WEB-INF` and everything is working now